# How to set Superscript in a TextBox in RDLC

Tags: c#, textbox, ssrs-2008, rdlc, superscript

I am trying to Superscript in a TextBox in RDLC and not getting any solution, to avoid this, I am using two text boxes one for main text and other for Superscript, and I am setting small font size to Superscript, may be RDLC have built-in function or formatting for Superscript, please suggest me better way to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the superscript html tag, , around the text you need in superscript. Then highlight the text and tags (or expression) and right click to open the properties window. Then in the text properties' general tab, select "HTML - Interpret html tags as styles".

```
<sup>"your text here"</sup>
```

Comment: The tag <sup> is getting ignored. How did you make it work?